# How to set the terminal for shell in gvim

Tags: terminal, wsl2

In gvim (started from WSL2), when I am executing a command, for example `:! ls -lha` the colors are not supported.
Also when the `:!man`  is executed, the following is reported:

> WARNING: terminal is not fully functional

Is there a way to fix that, i.e. to set a terminal that supports colors ?

Comment: try `:set guioptions+=!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Christian Brabandt suggested,
`:set guioptions+=!` solves the problem.

```
  '!'   External commands are executed in a terminal window.  Without
    this flag the MS-Windows GUI will open a console window to
    execute the command.  The Unix GUI will simulate a dumb
    terminal to list the command output.
    The terminal window will be positioned at the bottom, and grow
    upwards as needed.
```